# Difference between ground cloves and clove powder?

Tags: substitutions, spices

Is there a difference between ground cloves and clove powder? Can I easily substitute one for the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, spices are commonly sold as "X powder" or "ground X". As far as I can tell, they are likely the same thing. The only thing I might imagine would be different would be the size of the grind.

I would imagine yes, you can substitute one for the other.

eg:
http://www.livestrong.com/article/497275-cinnamon-powder-vs-ground-cinnamon/

Comment: From a little searching, it looks like herbal supplement type folks tend to say "clove powder" more often (I guess it sounds more like a medicine than a spice that way?) and it's a bit less common for things sold as spices, at least in the US. But yeah, definitely same thing.